# Low-quality-answer flag declined

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/536331/158442) as low quality since it does try to answer, but misses the point completely: the question is how to make Firefox magnet links in Transmission, not how to manually do so. Was I wrong in flagging?

Comment: I see you didn't down vote it...

Comment: @Mateo I expected it to get deleted quickly so i didn't down vote. I'll do so now that it's still here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, upon looking at the post again, you are correct, it should have been deleted (and now is). I apologize. I'm not really sure what happened when I declined it, but I think I got the answers mixed up and thought you had flagged [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/438352/44179), which doesn't really fit the low quality flag.

---

A couple of other things I think I should point out:

Please do downvote bad answers, even if you believe they will be shortly deleted as there really isn't any reason not to (the reputation will be returned once the post is removed).

The "very low quality" flag (VLQ) is a rather confusing flag, both for the people using it and the moderators handling it. I could understand someone declining the flag because the post, at first glance, doesn't look like it meets the criteria. Even at a closer look I'm not sure VLQ was the best flag to use. The flag states:

> This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

It didn't have severe formatting problems that couldn't be solved by editing. It *might* have severe content problems (as it doesn't even answer the question as asked), but I'm not really sure what severe content problems entails.

If I hadn't gotten the answers confused I would have approved it and deleted the answer. Next time though, (when there hopefully won't be any confusion on the moderators part) using a custom flag would be more helpful, especially since I regularly decline VLQ flags because of the aforementioned fogginess surrounding its use.

Comment: Yes, VLQ is somewhat unclear. I picked it as the answer isn't spam or offensive and does attempt to answer (even if it's the wrong question), and I usually use custom flags when I want to request something (ban for persistent spamming, for example). But [you're right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122447/270345) - the right way to go about this is to downvote, not pester moderators.

Comment: @muru Flagging it is appropriate, I was simply pointing out VLQ isn't necessarily the best option to pick :) (and this had nothing to do with me mistakenly declining the flag).